# Trim a shape in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I am drawing a geometric pattern in inkscape. I have faced a problem. In the white rectangle shown below, I need to make it into a trapezium. I drew two triangles at two sides of the rectangle with three lines. I tried to fill in the shape. But it is not possible to fill and also to cut these two triangles. Can anyone please help me with this? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select the rectangle, and one of the triangles. Holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> as you click to select will allow you to make more than one selection.

Click *Path > Difference*, and then repeat for the other side.

[image]